# How to put NOINDEX,FOLLOW to login and registration page Magento2.x

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I am having trouble in putting `meta robots` in selective page. I wanted to `Noindex` and `Follow` on login and registration page only and rest of page will have `Index` and `Follow`.

I have put `<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW"/>` in `/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` file but it causes to appear on whole site.

The block I have put in above file for reference.

```
// Path- /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</page>
```

Is there any way so I can put some condition here or any other best way to do it.

I am using `Magento ver.2.2.6`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you'd do this in your theme rather than in /vendor/magento - however that aside, you should be adding this content to
* customer_account_login.xml
* customer_account_create.xml

rather than default.xml. As you noted, default.xml will make it appear everywhere, adding to these two files will only affect login and registration pages.

Comment: Thank you very much. You save my day